# Basic calculator with processing (Android)

Tags: android, processing, calculator

I am trying to create basic calculator using processing. This is part the code:

```
RadioButtons r, r1, r2;
void setup()
{
  size(720,1280);

  String [] radioNames = {" 1 ", " 2 ", " 3 "};
  r= new RadioButtons(radioNames,3 ,60,500,200,200, HORIZONTAL);
  r.setNames(radioNames);
 }

void draw()
{
    r.display(); 
    if(r.get()==0)
      println("1");
    if(r.get() == 1)
      println("2");
    if(r.get() == 2)
      println("3"); 
}
```

It supposed to print the number which is being pressed. But it doesn't happen. 
The buttons are created correctly, but they dont work, r.get() is not working.... 
Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you setting the `onClickListern` or have you specified anywhere that which function to execute when it is clicked?

Comment: Yes. Where have you set the onClickLister when any one of it is clicked? Also `RadioButtons` seems to be a custom class.. is it? Because `RadioButton` is the class defined by android but `RadioButtons` seems different.